# Django plaintext template

Tags: django, templates, plaintext, templatetag

I'm currently writing a template which mostly outputs my fields and it's contents from the database as plaintext so that it can be downloaded (supposed to be a configuration file for ltsp) and I'm in a bind.

I often do things like this:

```
{% for model in modelqueryset %}
...
{% ifnotequal model.fieldx "" %}
    fieldx = {{ model.fieldx }}
{% endifnotequal %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

"..." is/are for a long list/a lot of entries of:

```
{% ifnotequal model.fieldy "" %}
    fieldy = {{ model.fieldy }}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

Now if the fieldx is in fact empty it displays an empty line however that just takes up unneccesary space and will make the plaintext difficult to read. **Now on to the question:**

How can I remove those empty lines? I tried {% spaceless %}...{% endspaceless %} and it doesn't really help. Do I have to write a custom templatetag or did I do something wrong or overlook something?

Any help is appreciated and I will also already say **Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an empty line because of a linebreak.

```
... <- here
{% ifnotequal model.fieldx "" %}
    fieldx = {{ model.fieldx }}
{% endifnotequal %}
```

So you can rewrite it like this

```
...{% ifnotequal model.fieldx "" %}
       fieldx = {{ model.fieldx }}
   {% endifnotequal %}
```

Or try [StripWhitespaceMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that StripWhitespaceMiddleware is the answer because I use mimetype="text/plain" in my view and as far as I can tell it only works with html. If I'm wrong please say so.

Comment: Actually I used normalize http://www.c-area.ch/code/django/templatetags/normalize.py

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a template for everything - it might be easier to use a plain HttpResponse constructor and build the text for output in Python:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse()
>>> response.write("<p>Here's the text of the Web page.</p>")
>>> response.write("<p>Here's another paragraph.</p>")
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DrTyrsa said, you can use [StripWhitespaceMiddleware](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/StripWhitespaceMiddleware).  Alternatively, if you only occasionally want to strip the whitespace, you can pull the core of this middleware out into a utility class like this:

```
import re
from django.template import loader, Context

class StripWhitespace():
    """
    Renders then strips whitespace from a file
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.left_whitespace = re.compile('^\s+', re.MULTILINE)
        self.right_whitespace = re.compile('\s+$', re.MULTILINE)
        self.blank_line = re.compile('\n+', re.MULTILINE)


    def render_clean(self, text_file, context_dict):
        context = Context(context_dict)
        text_template = loader.get_template(text_file)
        text_content = text_template.render(context)
        text_content = self.left_whitespace.sub('', text_content)
        text_content = self.right_whitespace.sub('\n', text_content)
        text_content = self.blank_line.sub('\n', text_content)
        return text_content
```

Then you can use it in your views.py like this:

```
def text_view(request):
    context = {}
    strip_whitespace = StripWhitespace()
    text_content = strip_whitespace.render_clean('sample.txt', context)
    return HttpResponse(text_content)
```

Note that I added a `blank_line` regular expression so you can remove ALL blank lines.  If you still want to see one blank line between sections, you can remove this regex.